# Trying to pass a list<object> from a page to an other

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Hi I'd like to pass arguments through pages in my application.
its working with string and int. But what i want to pass is a list
What I'm actually doing :

MainPage :

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["file"] = file;
NavigationService.Navigate(
  new Uri(string.Format("/gamepage.xaml"), UriKind.Relative));
```

SecondPage :

```
file = (Elements)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["file"];
```

File looks like that : `Elements file`

And Elements : `list<Element>`

Arriving my file is empty Oo. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to over ride the `OnNavigatedFrom` [method][1]

On `DestinationPage`, create the property of your complex type

```
public List<string> SomeComplexProperty {get;set;}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  // NavigationEventArgs will return  "DestinationPage"
    DestinationPage _page = e.Content as DestinationPage;
    if (_page!= null)
    {

        _page.SomeComplexProperty = listObject;
    }
}
```

[1]:

Comment: What do you mean by " NavigationEventArgs will return  "DestinationPage" ?

Comment: what i mean is this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: "the type DestinationPage" could not be found, thats what i didn't understand

Comment: DestinationPage would be the new page where you be navigating to. In your case, I think its "gamepage"